# Prove by probabilistic method that exists colored G in 3 colors which at least 2/3 of edges are legal

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

> Let be G=(V,E) un-directed graph. for coloring vertex of the graph we define "legal edge" which means the color of vertices in this edge are colored in different colors. Prove by probabilistic method that exists colored G in 3 colors which at least 2/3 of edges are legal.

I am able to prove it by induction method - but I don`t know how prove it formally by probabilistic method. if we raffle a graph, how can we say that the probability is bigger than 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:  if you colour the vertices at random from the $3$ colours (independently with equal probabilities)

- what is the probability that a particular edge is "legal"?
- what is the expected proportion of legal edges?
- what can you conclude?

Comment: Thank you! After color the vertices at random from the 3-colors.
The probability for a particular edge to be "legal" is $\frac {2}{3}$.
Then, if we define an indicator $f_i$ which means that $i$ edge is legal then $f=f_1+f_2+...+f_m$ when $\Omega=E$ and $|E|=m$ is the number of edges.
then $\mathbb{E}[f_i]=Pr(f_i=1)=\frac {2}{3}$. then $\mathbb{E}[f]=\sum_{i=1}^m\mathbb{E}[f_i]=\frac {2}{3}\cdot m$. 
since m>1 then we can conclude that probability that there exist colored G in 3 colors which at least $\frac {2}{3}$ of edges are legal.

Comment: @JohnD.  As you say, the answer to my first two questions is $\frac{2}{3}$.  I would then say that since this is an average over all possible colourings, at least one such possible colouring must have at least $\frac23$ of the edges legal.